# How do you extract the a string like "cart_item" from an instance of the model CartItem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose we have a model CartItem, and somewhere in the code we have an instance of that model, @my_example_cart_item.  What's the cleanest way to use that instance and get to the String "cart_item"?  I need the string to use as a scope in an I18N lookup.  The following works, but seems awfully verbose:

```
@my_example_cart_item.class.model_name.underscore.downcase
# 'cart_item'
```

Comment: `@my_example_cart_item.class.to_s.underscore` should do the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is verbose, but it's clear.  If it's something you'll do often, create a method to express this more tersely.